# Magento: custom option product on add to cart, remove already added products

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, magento, product

I'm facing the issue. Whenever i add custom option product into cart it remove all the already added cart products and only show the last one which i have added.

Comment: What version of Magento are you running, and how much has the CMS been customized? (Themes, Core Files, Etc...) If there have been heavy customizations made, you might want to try switching back to the default theme, and seeing if the problem persists.

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0. This only happening with custom option products while products without custom option adding normally and don't remove the old products

Comment: That sort of behavior is definitely not native to out-of-the-box Magento, and would only occur if a module, or modification to Theme or Core files were overriding or augmenting default functions. My suggested course of action would be to disable all plugins and revert to the base theme temporarily to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: i revert back to the default theme but issue still exist, now let me disable module one by one and check this issue, that may help to resolve this

Comment: I just check by disabling module one by one and with upload new all directory files of app/code/core/mage/checkout but still same issue